# Prove that $R=\{(M_1,M_2)\in P(N)\times P(N)|M_1\cap M_2=S\}$, for a fixed $S\in P(N)$, with $S\neq N$, $S\neq\varnothing$ is transitive

Tags: relations

It is not so clear to me whether this relation is transitive. I have two ideas, one - relation transitive, other - non-transitive.

1. I have so proved that you are transitive:

Let $M_1RM_2 \iff M_1 \cap M_2 = S$, $M_2RM_3 \iff M_2 \cap M_3 = S$, for a fixed $S \in P(N)$, with $S \in N$, $S \neq \varnothing$.

$M_2$ occurs in both equations $\implies$ $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$ have the same elements in common, since they are linked to $\cap$.

I.e., $M_1 \cap M_2 = S \iff M_1RM_3$, i.e., transitively.

2. But I can also think with the counterexample (maybe I don’t quite understand what “a fixed $S$” is):

Let $M_1 = \{1, 2\}$, $M_2 = \{2, 3\}$, $M_3 = \{3, 4\}$.

Then $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{2\} = S_1$, $M_2 \cap M_3 = \{3\} = S_2$.

But then $M_1 \cap M_3 = \varnothing = S_3$. Not transitive, since $S_3$ should not be empty.

I cannot understand where I make the mistakes.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Both 1 and 2 are wrong. Please note: $S$ is FIXED. There is no "$S_1, S_2, S_3$". There is a **single** set $S$ out there such that any pair of $M_1, M_2$ are related only if their intersection is this *unchanging* set $S$. In (2), If $M_1$ is related to $M_2$, that would mean $S = \{2\}$. Otherwise they would not be related. But that means $M_2$ is not related to $M_3$ since their intersection is $\{3\}$, not $S$. So the fact that $M_1$ is also not related to $M_3$ says nothing about whether $R$ is transitive.

Comment: (1) is false because your explanation of it is nonsense. It is literally you waving your hands and babbling because you didn't bother to look closely at what is going on. $R$ is not transitive, but you need to consider the counter-example more carefully.